# Vitest React Router mock not called

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, vitest

I'm migrating from jest to vitest and encountered an issue while checking if the `navigate()` function returned from the `useNavigate()` hook was called:

vitest setup.ts:

```
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';
import { expect, vi } from 'vitest';

expect.extend(matchers);

export const mockNavigate = vi.fn();

vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
    const router = await vi.importActual<typeof import('react-router-dom')>('react-router-dom');
    return {
        ...router,
        useNavigate: vi.fn().mockReturnValue(mockNavigate),
    };
});
```

Component test:

```
import React from 'react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from 'vitest';
import { SigninComponent } from '../../../../../../src/features/auth/components/signin.component';
import { renderWithProviders } from '../../../../utils';
import { mockNavigate } from '../../../../setup';

describe('Signin Component', () => {
   it('navigates to signup page', async () => {
        renderWithProviders(<SigninComponent />);
   
        userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('test-nav-btn'));
        await screen.findByText('AppName');

        expect(mockNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/signup');
    });
});
```

Render with providers helper:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { gqlClient } from '../../src/common/gql/gql-auth';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { store } from '../../src/common/state/store';

export const renderWithProviders = (component: ReactNode) => {
    return render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ApolloProvider client={gqlClient}>
                <MemoryRouter>{component}</MemoryRouter>
            </ApolloProvider>
        </Provider>,
    );
};
```

Encountered error:

> ```
> AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ '/signup' ]
> Received:
> Number of calls: 0
> ```

Comment: It's kind of against RTL's testing methodology to test internal implementation details. Why not test the UI by interacting with it and testing the navigation action happened by asserting the new expected UI is in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on which version of user-event you are using you may need to await the click in your test.  If you are using @testing-library/react v14 then you need to follow the guide here: [Writing tests with userEvent @testing-library/react v14](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/intro)

so you import user-event as 'userEvent' and in your test setup you store the return value from userEvent.setup() init function in a variable called 'user'

then await the user.click() call in your test.

```
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

// inlining
test('trigger some awesome feature when clicking the button', async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()
  // Import `render` and `screen` from the framework library of your choice.
  // See https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/install#wrappers
  render(<MyComponent />)

  await user.click(screen.getByRole('button', {name: /click me!/i}))

  // ...assertions...
})
```

but as Reese mentioned, you're effectively testing the RTL internal code.

Comment: thanks, that also resovles the issue, however for now i sticked to fireEvent